# ng-grid cell template default value not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I've copied the default cell template string into my gridOption definition but the behavior is completely different than not defining the cellTemplate.  It has something to do with custom filters for the cell but I can't figure out why there is a difference.

```
<span ng-cell-text>{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</span>
```

If I leave out the 'CUSTOM_FILTERS' then the cell displays the unfiltered value.  If I add the 'CUSTOM_FILTERS', then the cell is blank and editing is not possible.

The filter is just a 'currency:"$"' filter.

If I explicitly spell out the content instead of letting ng-grid do the replacement, then it works fine.

```
<span ng-cell-text>{{row.getProperty(col.field) | currency:"$"}}</span>
```

Anyone know why this is happening? This is with ng-grid 2.08

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/liG8K0?p=preview)

Comment: can you add a fiddle so I can understand more about the problem?

Comment: I've added a Plunker.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646724/ng-grid-celltemplate-doesnt-work-with-custom-filters-included This previous SO questions explains that the cellfilter is not applied when there is a cellTemplate (as can be seen in the sourcecode here :  https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/src/classes/column.js )

Comment: @AardVark I should have searched more.  Thank you.